# What does it mean when we let a trait inherits 'static?

Tags: rust, static, traits, lifetime

Rust supports trait inheritance, as follows:

```rust
pub trait A {}
pub trait B: A {}
```

`B: A` means that if some type `T` implements `B`, it also needs to implement all the methods in `A`.

But today I see the following code:

```rust
trait Display: 'static {
    fn print(&self);
}
```

What does it mean? It doesn't seem to be trait inheritance.

Comment: "Inheritance" might be the wrong mental model here. `trait B: A` just means "if you implement B, you must also implement A". For the _user_ of the trait, this has similar effect to that of inheritance because they can require `B` and count on getting `A` as well. But an _implementor_ of B experiences no inheritance, they have to also (and separately) implement A. In that light, `Display: 'static` means that, as a user of `Display`, you can count that the type that implements it has a `'static` lifetime bound, which means that it doesn't borrow non-static data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust doesn't have inheritance.

What it has is a way to define constraints. For example a trait may be constrained to only be implemented by types which implement another trait.

In your case the constraint is a [lifetime bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html#trait-object-lifetime-bounds).

To implement your `Display` trait, an object may contain references but in this case their lifetime must respect this constraint.

Let's suppose you have this type:

```rust
struct S<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}
```

Then you can't implement the trait for any lifetime, but only `'static`.

```rust
impl Display for S<'static> {
    fn print(&self){}
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = "test";
    let a = S { s: s1 };
    a.print(); // compiles

    let s2 = "test".to_string();
    let a = S { s: &s2 };
    a.print(); // doesn't compile because s doesn't live long enough
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Rust supports trait inheritance, as follows [...] B: A means that if some type T implements B, it also needs to implement all the methods in A.

Technically, that is not *inheritance* but *requirement*. It is a [trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html) not entirely dissimilar to one you'd have in a function: it constraints the type on which B is implement*able* to only types on which A is already implemented.

With that change in wording, the second version is much easier to understand: it's a *lifetime bound*, meaning it constraints the type on which B is implementable to only types with `'static` lifetime, meaning if you're trying to implement B on a type, that must either have no lifetime at all, or have a `'static` lifetime (or the implementation must have a lifetime bound aka only work for *some* uses of the type).

You can see that if you try to implement the trait on a lifetime-generic structure:

```rust
struct A<'a>(&'a str);
trait Display: 'static {
    fn print(&self);
}

impl <'a>Display for A<'a> {
    fn print(&self) { todo!() }
}
```

will yield

> error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied

That is because `'a` can be anything, so implementing `Display` for `A<'a>` means it is also implemented for non-`'static` instances, which is not valid.

By adding the relevant lifetime bound *on the impl*, and thus limiting the implementation to `A<'static>` instances:

```rust
struct A<'a>(&'a str);
trait Display: 'static {
    fn print(&self);
}

impl <'a: 'static>Display for A<'a> {
    fn print(&self) { todo!() }
}
```

the requirements *of the trait* are satisfied, and the impl is valid (nb: the `'a` is not necessary here you can just `impl ... for A<'static>`, I'm showing it for regularity).

And if your struct has no lifetime it works by default, because no lifetime ~ `'static`:

```rust
struct A(String);
trait Display: 'static {
    fn print(&self);
}

impl Display for A {
    fn print(&self) { todo!() }
}
```